# Using CanCan with a static roles list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cas

I’m looking to set up simple role based access on my rails app without using a database, we use CAS to handle the authentication so can capture the username from the CAS variables.

My thought was to map usernames to specific roles in a hash (in application.rb, see below for an idea)) and then use that role to determine if the content is viewable.

```
ROLES = { 
        'admin' => [ 'username1', 'username2'],
        'standard_user' => ['username3']
        }
```

I’ve been advised to look at the CanCan gem but that seems to want to get the role information from a user model which I don’t want to setup, mainly because we intend to pass over role information as another CAS variable in the near future.

So I wondered if anyone has any idea if this plan is do-able and maybe point me in the direction of any code snippets that might help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with this kind of setup, you should be able to use cancan.  If you have a user model where you store the `username` and the ability is revolving around this model, try the following on `ability.rb`

```
# user.rb
ROLES = {
  admin: %w[username1 username2],
  standard_user: %w[username3]
}

# ability.rb
user ||= User.new # username is blank

if User::ROLES[:admin].include?(user.username)
  can :manage, :all

elsif User::ROLES[:standard_user].include?(user.username)
  cannot :manage, Invoices

else
  ...
end
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll test this later today and if it works will mark this as the answer